Linux Ошибка VirtualBox
Установил на VirtualBox OC Linux, но когда я добавил гостевой ОС начал писать ошибку.
Ошибка:

Необработанное исключение win32 произошло в "[17576] VirtualBoxVM.exe"



А так то память тестировали, например, у компа точно нет проблем с памятью в частности?

Ха, может. Но я щас просто купид SSD диск н а1 тб и загрузил этот же файл линукс всё работает. Спасибо за коммент)
